# TestCafe DropDown selector

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, testcafe

I am trying to select a dynamic drop down value on testcafe.

The value "select2-result-label-7" remains the same expect for the last number. How could I select the right drop down?I tried pattern matching but no luck.

Could help me how to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article in the documentation that describes how to work with dynamics selectors: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#select-elements-with-dynamic-ids

Please also take a look at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors article. You can find a lot of examples how to work with dynamic attributes there.